# Как при клике на блок, курсор переводился на Input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно при клике на на button имитировалось нажатие на инпут и курсор появлялся там и сразу можно было вводить, как будто мы и нажали на инпут

```css
button { width: 100px; height: 40px}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button>кнопка</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button onclick="document.querySelector('input').focus()">кнопка</button>
```